# Read large XLS and put into Array is very slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spreadsheet

I have a large XLS file with postal codes, the problem: is a quite slow to read the data, for example, the file have multiple sheets with the state name, into each sheet they are a multiple rows with postal code, neighborhoods and municipality. The file have 33 states, each state have between 1000 and 9000 rows.

I try to parse this to an array of hashes, which one take 22 seconds. Is there any way to read this faster?

This is how I read the sheet

```rb
    def read_sheet(sheet_name:, offset: 1)
      sheet = file.worksheet sheet_name[0..30]
      clean_data = sheet.each_with_index(offset)
                        .lazy
                        .reject{|k, _| !k.any?}

      data = clean_data.map do |row, _index|
        DATA_MAPPING.map do |field, column|
          { field => row[column] }
        end.inject(:merge)
      end

      yield data
    end
```

And I retrieve all with

```rb
    def read_file
      result = {}
      sheets_titles.each_with_index do |name|
        read_sheet(sheet_name: name) do |data|
          result.merge! name => data.to_a
        end
      end
      result
    end
```

So, if I use .to_a or .to_json or any method to process the data and insert to DB, I have to wait few seconds ... any suggestion?

Comment: Do you have the option of converting the input to CSVs, or even just XLSX? XLS is a very, very inefficient data storage format

Comment: yes, I know ... but the requirement, in this case, is only with XLS format ... so, if I want to convert the file, must be on runtime, which maybe is more slow

Comment: I will not necessarily make your code more performant but do you use `each_with_index` in both methods although you do not use the `index` at all? Additionally, using `map` instead of `each` to populate the output might be more memory efficient.